# What is the origin of the name JOE - the dye used to mark DNA sequences?

Tags: dna-rna, dye

I came across an article where JOE - a dye used to mark DNA sequences was mentioned. It was also stated that no one knows the origin of the name for the dye. Does anyone here have any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: These are just trade names to be used by common users who do not care about the chemical structure. Just like KitKat is a chocolate...easy to pronounce and easy to remember. Such names have zero scientific or scholarly value. You have FAM, TAMRA, Alexa Fluor dyes etc.

Comment: @AChem - sure, but somebody came up with the name somehow. Perhaps there is a back story, perhaps not. By the early 90's they  (FAM, JOE, ...) just appeared in the literature. Somebody active back then may have some insight into just why particular dyes got their particular names.

Comment: @JonCuster, The problem with commercial stuff is that they do not publish or are not allowed to publish. All these names have a TM (trademark) sign over them. I am sure there must be an internal story in the company and it might be best to contact the manufacturer. I had checked SciFinder for the OP to look at the synonyms. Nothing useful there. Sometimes companies do respond to such requests provided the email is written seriously with a genuine effort.

Comment: As per Wikipedia, at Alexa-Fluor dyes named after their son Alex Haugland, son of Richard and Rosaria Haugland (company owners). So it will not be surprising to find that Joe is also a son of a chemist! Best source would be the company itself.